# How can I change the colour of a particular word list within a docx file?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am setting up a Powershell script that by passing the path to a directory, checks if any of the strings contained in an excel file appear in the doc or docx files in that directory. If so, the colour of that string has to be changed in the doc/docx file.
I've been messing around with Word's COM object for a while and haven't been able to get it to work.
Here is what I have so far

```
#Open a Folder Browser to select the folder to process
$fwd = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$null = $fwd.ShowDialog()
$path = $fwd.SelectedPath
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path| Where-Object -Property Extension -Match ".docx?"

#Load the excel file data to an arraylist object for late iteration
$forbiddenWordsFilePath = "<<Path_To_XLSX>>"
$forbiddenWords= Import-Excel -Path $forbiddenWordsFilePath

$WordDoc = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$WordDoc.visible=$false

#Iterate over the files contained on the folder
foreach ($file in $files) {

#Make a backup of the docx file previous to working with it
$fileBackupPath= $file.FullName+"_bck"    
Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $fileBackupPath

#Opens the docx? file on background
$doc = $WordDoc.Documents.Open($file.FullName,[type]::Missing,$true)

$MatchCase = $false
$MatchWholeWorld = $true
$MatchWildcards = $false
$MatchSoundsLike = $false
$MatchAllWordForms = $false
$Forward = $false
$Wrap = 1
$Format = $true
$wdReplaceAll  = 2

#Iterate over the words list and search for them on the docx file

foreach ($word in $forbiddenWords){    
    $Replace=$word.Search_Pattern
    $doc.Content.Find.Execute($word.Search_Pattern, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWorld, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, $Replace, $wdReplaceAll)
    
}

}

#Clears any opened Microsoft Word process
$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$WordDoc)
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Remove-Variable WordDoc
```

It is clear to me that the colour change should be in the second foreach. But I am not able to find the code that allows me to do it.
I'm a bit of a novice in dealing with the Word COM object with Powershell.

The excel file has the following headers....
`Control_Type Control Comments Search_Pattern`

In case there are doubts about how to obtain the property "Search_word".

Comment: You are forgetting to save the updated document at the end and quit Word: `$doc.Close($true); $WordDoc.Quit()`. After that release the COM objects from memory (both `$doc` and `$WordDoc`). Also test to see what `$forbiddenWords` contains. I doubt if that is a string array..

Comment: Hi `$forbiddenWords` is an arraylist of objects which have as property names the excel headers I mentioned on my question. These properties are of type String.